# "In term of" vs. "in terms of"?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english, writing

What is the difference between `in term of` and `in terms of` ?
Are both used in writing ?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try looking both of them up in an online dictionary?  I think you will only find *in terms of*.

Comment: It's a good question. Why was it closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Referencing this [article](http://xaivierchia.blogspot.ca/2011/02/common-mistakes-in-terms-of-vs-in-term.html):

> According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, "in terms of" can be used for describing either plural or singular fact or event.
>
> Here are two examples from the dictionary:
>   1. Femininity is still defined in terms of **beauty**. (Beauty is singular)
>   2. It's too early to start talking in terms of **casualties**. (casualties is plural)
>
> "In term of", on the other hand, does not exist in the dictionary. Nevertheless, we still can use "a term of", "in the long term", etc.